# How to parse CSV-based IF conditions

Tags: ruby, csv, rubygems

I'm trying to parse a CSV report which I'm calling from Nexpose's API:

```
 nsc.list_reports.each do | report |
  puts report.name
  report_id = report.config_id
  report_summary = nsc.generate_report(report_id, true)

  report = nsc.download(report_summary.uri)
  puts report    


  csv = CSV.read(report, :headers => true, :converters => :all).select do|row|
    row['number available'] > 0 && row['Score'] >=9
  end

  csv.each do |row|
    puts row['name']
  end
end
```

but basically this is the format of what it gives me

```
ID,name,title,Score,number available
1,"test1","title1",4,3
2,"test2","title2",8,0
3,"test3","title3",9,0
4,"test4","title4",10,6
5,"test5","title5",5,22
6,"test6","title6",9,1
7,"test7","title7",2,5
```

My goal is to only find the ones that have a "score" >=9 and "number available" >0. So in this example, it should return 'test4' and 'test6'

Comment: _WHAT_ CSV are you trying to parse? Please read "[mcve]" and the linked page. We need the minimal code demonstrating the problem, the minimal input (CSV) supporting that code that demonstrates the problem and the expected output. You gave us the expected output but no way to get to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't convert the headers to symbols; use `select`, not `detect`; and some minor details:

```
csv = CSV.read(report, :headers => true, :converters => :all).select do|row|
   row['number available'] > 0 && row['Score'] >=9}
end    

csv.each do |row|
  puts row["name"]
end
```

Comment: from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/csv.rb:1256:in `open'
 from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/csv.rb:1256:in `open'
 from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/csv.rb:1330:in `read'
 from C:/Users/1/RubymineProjects/nexpose/main.rb:26:in `block in <top (required)>'
 from C:/Users/RubymineProjects/nexpose/main.rb:18:in `each'
 from C:/Users/RubymineProjects/nexpose/main.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
 from -e:1:in `load'
 from -e:1:in `<main>'

Comment: Try copy-pasting this code right after your `puts report` line